# Android how to invisible my listview?

Tags: java, android, listview, search

I am using my own data base and get specific column and display listview. Here using `addTextChangedListener` method like this:

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.main , R.id.product_name, optionlist);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter); 

 inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() { 
   @Override
      public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // When user changed the Text                   
         MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);                              
        }    
    @Override
      public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {      
        }               
        @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {                   
    }
});
```

My Question is: When I search data in edit text that time only specific data visible other wise no data display in my listview how to solve my problem here.

Here search time data visible like this othe wise no data visible

[image: Here search time data visible like this otherwise no data visible]

I want this no search no data visible in list view:

[image]

but here data visible like this:

[image]

Comment: it's better to clear the adapter than hiding listview.

Answer (score 1):

That's difference between *Filter* and *Search*. You are filtering data, with no filter applied, everything is selected. Easiest would be to call `setVisibility(GONE)` on `ListView` when `TextView` is empty. Or you can place a `boolean` switch in `Adapter` to return item count as 0, when switch is set true.

Answer (score 0):

add following to your listview in xml

```
android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
```

Answer (score 0):

Only add following to your java class:

```
@Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // When user changed the Text

            lv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
            String str = inputSearch.getText().toString();
            if (str.equals("")) {
                lv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Its better you clear the adapter and set empty string to adapter

```
@Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
        // When user changed the Text

        lv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
        String str = inputSearch.getText().toString();
        if (str.equals("")) 
        {
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            list.add("");
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(TestSpinner.this,R.layout.spinner_item,list);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
```